# Regex: How to check if a string is not empty or blank and does not contain the character "<" and ">"?

Tags: regex

I have to use a regex to verify if a string is not empty or blank, and doesn't contain ">" "<".

For example:

[image]

1. "    " is invalid;
2. " a <" is invalid;
3. " a 6" is OK;

I tried below regex, but doesn't work.

---

> ^(^\s*$)|^[^<,>]+$

---

How could I set this regex? could any kind guys help me on this? thanks.

Comment: Do not understand why associated this to a different question, that's a big different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^(?!\s+$)[^<>]+$
```

- `^...$` - String should start and end with... (matching whole string/line)

  - `(?!...)` - Negative lookahead, string should not be followed by...

    - `\s+$` - One or more whitespace characters until the end of the string
  - `[^<>]+` - Any character except `<` and `>`, one or more times

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/6hPI45/1)

Comment: thanks, it works! ?! is so useful!